# Update row in Eben using play framework 2.5.4 java

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3, ebean

I am trying to update a field **balance** in Eben Playframework Java 2.5.4
using this code

`this.parentObject.update();`

**initially the value of Balance is 0** and my expected result,

```
this.parentObject.balance = balance + 500;
```

after the above code is **balance = 500;**

[image]

balance = 500 is what I need and my debug(2nd last line of 1st screenshot) is also showing the same.

But when I firing query using this code

```
List<MlmModel> list = this.parentObject.find.all();
```

**It is showing balance = 0 and not 500** (plz see 2nd screenshot).

Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image: This is my debug Result]

Comment: Check again if while updating the balance, parentObject "ID" is actually set i.e. it is not zero? Also do you get any error in logs? What query do you get for that update?

Comment: Try refresh the object before the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the setter methods to update a value using Ebean.

So instead of:

```
this.parentObject.balance = balance + 500;
this.parentObject.update();
```

it should be:

```
this.parentObject.setBalance(balance + 500);
this.parentObject.update();
```